# How to properly maintain one commit per feature branch strategy in a GIT workflow?

Tags: git, git-amend

In a project I am working on, we have workflow of one commit per feature branch. If I have not to make any subsequent changes after a commit, then it is fine, but if after a commit, and which has been pushed too to remote, I have to make some changes, how to make sure there still is one commit in that branch? I am currently using git commit --amend but that changes commit hashes. Is there a way that I still have one commit and the commit id is not changed? or what is the best approach/alternative to using git commit --amend? Or amend should be fine?

Regards

Comment: Question: If you _haven't_ yet pushed a feature branch yet, then why does it matter if the commit hashes change?  Note that you can't rewrite the history of Git branch without introducing new commits (generally).

Comment: You are right, in that case, I don't need to worry, but if changes have been pushed, then it is a concern as commit --amend changes commit hashes

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way that I still have one commit and the commit id is not changed?

No, there isn't. *You cannot change a commit.* If you could, Git itself would break. If you rewrite history in any way, you make completely *new* commits, with *new* commit hashes, *replacing* the commits whose history is rewritten.

> if after a commit, and which has been pushed too to remote, I have to make some changes, how to make sure there still is one commit in that branch?

Basically, don't get into that position. Rewriting history that has been pushed is *bad* — potentially *very* bad. If you do it, you will have to use `force` to push the rewritten history, and if the branch is shared with others, it is very possible that terrible things will happen to those who share the repository with you.

Behave responsibly: work on a branch, rewrite the branch, do whatever you like to the branch, *locally.* Commit early and often, and then, if the rule is that there should only be one commit, squash all the commits down to one. Fine, as long as that is purely *local* and you have *never* pushed this branch. If you are worried about backup, you can even push the branch to an *unshared* location. But *do not push* to a *shared* branch until you are quite certain that you have finished.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually there are times when some QA comments come up on feature branches which could be some very small changes. Doing them in the same branches makes more sense, so in that case, I need to make new commits in the same branch and push again.

Comment: Yes, but then insisting that it be squashed down to one commit might be too dogmatic.